# Application only works in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, runnable

I'm doing a college project using Java and Eclipse. The app works perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it as Runnable Java File it doesn't work. No any error is shown, and nothing is opened.

Do you have any tutorial about how to export it correctly? The application is too long to post here. However, if you need to see any part of code just ask.

**EDIT : Error returned by console**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnecti
on$JarURLInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.BufferedInputStream
```

Comment: How did you run the jar?

Comment: I ran it directly by double click, and It didn't do nothing.

Comment: Try java -jar <nameOfJar>, you can see the error.

Comment: Is it a gui application or just a service?I would suggest you to open the taskManager and click on the processes tab, when you double click on this jar file look for this process to see if it's running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem! I don't know why, but It was caused by BufferedInputStream so I changed it by InputStream and the application works perfectly, thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one good article on jar creation and execution http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-create-and-execute-jar-file-in.html